# Setting maximum quantity based on quantity available

Tags: loops, ms-access, for-loop, vba

I am creating an order form on Access in which I want to display a combo box per product where the maximum quantity is based on the quantity that is available.

I have a table:

Inventory (ItemID (pk), QtyAvailable)

What I am trying to do is a for loop where the quantity would keep adding 1 until it reaches quantity available. Below is the code I used:

```html
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim qtyAvailable As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Qty As Integer

    Set qtyAvailable = DLookup("QtyAvailable", "Inventory", "ItemID = 'FSK606'")

    For i = 1 To qtyAvailable Step 1
        Me.cboxqty.Value = Qty + i
    Next i

End Sub
```

I get an error saying "Compile error: Object required" and it highlights qtyAvailable. Any help or suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your DLookup an excel function? If so you could just use a count excel function on the range to get your quantity without that for loop.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I am doing this over on Access. @Alex Weber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qtyAvailable` is a variable of type Integer. `Set` is only used for **object** variables. It's simply

```
qtyAvailable = DLookup("QtyAvailable", "Inventory", "ItemID = 'FSK606'")
```

What is your loop supposed to do?
Why don't you simply do

```
Me.cboxqty.Value = qtyAvailable
```

**EDIT**

You probably want each quantity from 1 to qtyAvailable as option in the combobox. You can't use `.Value` for that, but [`.AddItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835377.aspx)

```
For i = 1 To qtyAvailable 
    Me.cboxqty.AddItem CStr(i)
Next i
```

The `RowSourceType` property of `cboxqty` must be set to "Value List".

Comment: Thanks @Andre451 This is exactly what I needed to do. So to clarify, you always want to set RowSourceType to "Value List" when you want to create any sort of list with loops?

Comment: @RonT: When you want to use `.AddItem` to set the combobox items via VBA, yes. Or for a fixed list of values that you set in the properties window.  Normally a combobox gets its data from a table or query.